# How can i know that the mouse has entered window in electron project?

Tags: electron

What do I want to do when the mouse entered the window with `-webkit-app-region: drag` attribute, then I find if I try to add the `-webkit-app-region: drag` attribute，the element invalidates all mouse event，include mouseenter and mouseleave.

I understand that the click event related to dragging, but why are events other same also failed

```
.app {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

function app() {
  return (
    <div 
      className={style['app']}
      onMouseEnter={() => console.log('enter')}
      onMouseLeave={() => console.log('leave')}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: try BrowserWindow 'focus' event if you want to do it for the window itself https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-focus

Comment: "<div class="app" style="-webkit-app-region:drag" onmouseenter="console.log('mouse entered')" onmouseleave="console.log('mouse left')">Hi</div>" (vanilla HTML) just works for me

Comment: @SudhakarRS thank for your comment, but 'focus' can't not meet my meets and  the same code can't work here.

Comment: If you try to render the app component what error are you getting?

Comment: Did't receive the error but did not response

Comment: kindly post your reactjs code, the way you render